# std::for_each ignoring default function argument

Tags: c++, boost, std

I stumbled on a strange compilation problem. I want to process a list of strings, using `std::for_each`. The following simplified code illustrates the problem :

```
# include <list>
# include <string>
# include <algorithm>

using namespace std ;

void f(wstring & str)
{
    // process str here
}

void g(wstring & str, int dummy = 0)
{
    // process str here, same as f, just added a second default dummy argument
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
    list<wstring> text ;

    text.push_back(L"foo") ;
    text.push_back(L"bar") ;

    for_each(text.begin(), text.end(), f) ;  // OK, fine :)
    for_each(text.begin(), text.end(), g) ;  // Compilation error, complains about 
                     // g taking 2 arguments, but called within std::for_each
                     // with only one argument. 

    // ...
    return 0 ;
}
```

I tested using MinGW 4.5.2 and MSVC10, both reported the same error message. Originally, I wanted to use `boost::algorithm::trim` as a processing function passed to `std::for_each`, but I found that it takes two arguments, the first being mandatory (the string to process) and the second one is optional (a locale providing a definition for space chars).

Is there any way to keep things clean when using `std::for_each`(and other standard algorithms) when having functions or methods with default arguments ? I found a way to make it work, but it is no more clear and easily understandable, so a `for` loop begins to seem easier ...

```
# include <list>    
# include <string>
# include <algorithm>
# include <boost/bind.hpp>
# include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std ;
using namespace boost ;

// ... somewhere inside main
list<wstring> text ;
for_each(text.begin(), text.end(), bind(algorithm::trim<wstring>, _1, locale()) ;
// One must deal with default arguments ...
// for_each(text.begin(), text.end(), algorithm::trim<wstring>) would be a real pleasure
```

Thanks for any help !

*Note* : I just started learning English, sorry for mistakes :)

Comment: I think that it simply doesn't work this way for functors. Remove the dummy argument.

Comment: The dummy argument I've added to `g` was to demonstrate the strange behaviour of `std::for_each`. Calling `g` with some `wstring str` like `g(str)` works like a charm, but not inside `std::for_each`. In my case, using `boost::algorithm::trim` directly as a functor is impossible without tricks, because of its second argument being optional (an std::locale)

Comment: @Overcoder: that's because `g(str)` immediately becomes `g(str, 0)` -- the default argument is just code generation sugar.

Comment: That's what I expected from the code, but it isn't the case. Here's what MinGW reported : d:\development\tools\mingw32\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4185:2: error: too few arguments to function

Comment: @overcoder: It's not "strange".

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I didn't understand why, as I guessed, g(str) is not expended to g(str, 0) when called inside the code generated for the templated `std::for_each` ? (see @Kerrek SB comment)

Comment: @overcoder: Kerrek's answer explains the situation, and it is not "strange". :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default arguments are just a code-generation tool and not part of the function signature, so you can't really get around that. You could wrap your function in a function object, but that's precisely what `bind` already does for you.

However, in C++0x you can conveniently store the result (and use `std::bind`) to maybe make the code a bit more readable:

```
auto trimmer = std::bind(boost::algorithm::trim<std::wstring>, std::placeholders::_1, std::locale());

std::for_each(text.begin(), text.end(), trimmer);
```

(The reason you don't want to do that in C++98/03 is that the return type of `bind` is something rather unsightly, and you wouldn't be doing anyone a favour by spelling it out.)

Alternatively, again in C++0x, you could use a lambda:

```
std::for_each(text.begin(), text.end(), [](std::wstring & s){ boost::algorithm::trim<std::wstring>(s); });
```

Comment: Also, if you stuck with current standard, take a look at bind2nd (indeed it has some requirements for functors - your g should be struct inherited from binary_function)

Comment: @vnm: yes, good point, one less boost dependency: `std::for_each(..., ..., std::bind2nd(boost::algorithm::trim<std::wstring>, std::locale()));`.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll see if I can enable C++0x for my current project. Lambdas seem more convenient.

Comment: @Overcoder: Up to you -- the binding syntax isn't really that terrible, it's just a matter of taste. It wouldn't be the end of the world to have this one line in there, it's still pretty self-explanatory code...